# PIXI.js - subscribe to events directly interacting with canvas

Tags: javascript, canvas, pixi.js

I'm trying to make a HTML UI over my canvas-based game. It works fine, except every click on my UI overlay also triggers a click on the canvas - it seems PIXI adds listeners to the window object (when I inspect the events received by the canvas, the original target is the window) and they flow through the "Interaction Manager" into my stage object.

I'm not sure how to disable that or if there's some kind of approved, not hacky workaround. I would want to only receive PIXI events if they interact with the canvas directly.

Comment: I don't know pixi.js, but if you add your own event to window, you can try to either `return false` or call `e.preventDefault` or something like that (take a look at event bubbling and how to prevent it).